# Convert from EPSG:4326 to UTM in PostGIS

Tags: gis, postgis, utm

I would like to **convert from EPSG:4326 to UTM (30N/EPSG:32630 or 29N/EPSG:32629) in PostGIS**. I do the following query but I get wrong results:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(36.5277099609375 -5.86424016952515)',4326),32630)) As check;
```

I get `"POINT(5262418.33128724 -839958.963432011)"` when it should be something approximate to `243625.00,4046330.00` in UTM 30N. If I do the conversion from 4326 to UTM I get the right result but not from UTM to 4326.

- What's wrong with the query?
- And are there anyway to get the UTM timezone from the coordinates in
  EPSG:4326 because I don't know if they belong to 30N or 29N?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) Your query is correct but you coordinates are inverted. The correct coordinates order in the [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) format is `POINT(x y)`, also `POINT(longitude latitude)`

This query give you the expected result:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-5.86424016952515 36.5277099609375)',4326),32630)) As check;
```

2) To get the UTM zone from a lat/long geometry you can use this formula:

```
ST_X(input_geometry)+180)/6)+1
```

with some adjustments.

For this purpose we use this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_utmzone(input_geom geometry)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   zone int;
   pref int;
BEGIN
   IF GeometryType(input_geom) != 'POINT' THEN
     RAISE EXCEPTION 'Input geom must be a point. Currently is: %', GeometryType(input_geom);
   END IF;
   IF ST_Y(input_geom) >0 THEN
      pref:=32600;
   ELSE
      pref:=32700;
   END IF;
   zone = floor((ST_X(input_geom)+180)/6)+1;
   RETURN zone+pref;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Use it with this query:

```
SELECT get_utmzone(ST_GeomFromText('POINT( -5.86424016952515 36.5277099609375)',4326));
```

The result should be `32630`

Comment: There is a little typo above. You must modify:

```SELECT utmzone(ST_GeomFromText('POINT( -5.86424016952515 36.5277099609375)',4326));```

with: 

```SELECT get_utmzone(ST_GeomFromText('POINT( -5.86424016952515 36.5277099609375)',4326));```

Comment: Source of the function? Perhaps https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2005-December/010253.html

Answer (score 1):

Firs thing is that following documentation of OpenGIS WKT Point(x,y) yours POINT(36.5277099609375 -5.86424016952515) is south of equator so you have to use 29S(EPSG:32729) and 30S(EPSG:32730)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because is not `POINT(36.5277099609375 -5.86424016952515)`, but `POINT(-5.86424016952515 36.5277099609375)`because longitude and latitude depends on the system. Normally X=longitude and Y=latitude, but e.g. in Google Maps X is the lat and Y is the long.

Comment: It is not an answer, may be a commet. Is only a reinforce to the 2015 text of Tommaso,  *"...your coordinates are inverted"*